# Adding recipients beyond "ReplyAll" in EWS

Tags: xml, web-services, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

If I want to reply to all the recipient of a mail in EWS, I can use the following XML:

```
<tns:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy">
  <tns:SavedItemFolderId>
    <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="sentitems"/>
  </tns:SavedItemFolderId>
  <tns:Items>
    <t:ReplyAllToItem>
      <t:ReferenceItemId Id="MailId" ChangeKey="MailChangeKey" />
      <t:NewBodyContent BodyType="HTML">body</t:NewBodyContent>
    </t:ReplyAllToItem>
  </tns:Items>
</tns:CreateItem>
```

This works great. But consider the scenario that you press the "Reply all" button and add a few extra email addressses that should recieve the mail.

How should I alter the XML to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [MessageDispositionType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/exchangewebservices.messagedispositiontype(v=exchg.150).aspx).  By setting MessageDisposition=SaveOnly in the line , you can create a draft.  Then, you can update the draft with the additional recipients you need, and send the message by calling UpdateItem and setting MessageDispostion=SendAndSaveCopy.